# Validate phonenumbers to specific format using Google Sheet formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image]

I'm working with google sheets and would like to convert US phone numbers to the format:

```
1xxxyyyzzzz
```

eg 402-333-4444 should be turned into 14023334444

I have an apps script validator function which does this:

```
var numbers = 'INVALID' 

if ( parsed_body.hasOwnProperty('PHONE') ) {


  var phone = parsed_body['PHONE'].toString();
  Logger.log(parsed_body);

  numbers = phone.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
  var firstChar = numbers.charAt(0);
  if ( firstChar !== '1'){ numbers = '1'+ numbers}
  Logger.log(numbers);

  if ( numbers.length !== 11){ numbers = 'NOTELEVEN'};
}

parsed_body['PHONE']=numbers;
```

but I'd like to make the sheet do this. Is this possible ?

Comment: Yes,  you could easily re-write this as a sheet formula using regexreplace, left and len.

Comment: Sorry about the delay Tom - Thank you!

Comment: Follow up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61279657/formatting-phone-number-in-place-in-sheet-cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works out to quite a long formula if you do it in a single formula, because you have to keep repeating the previous steps, unlike in the script version:

```
=if(len(if(left(regexreplace(""&D2,"[^0-9]",""))="1","","1")&regexreplace(""&D2,"[^0-9]",""))=11,
if(left(regexreplace(""&D2,"[^0-9]",""))="1","","1")&regexreplace(""&D2,"[^0-9]",""),"INVALID")
```

[image]

May be changed to an array formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(D2:D="","",if(len(if(left(regexreplace(""&D2:D,"[^0-9]",""))="1","","1")&regexreplace(""&D2:D,"[^0-9]",""))=11,
if(left(regexreplace(""&D2:D,"[^0-9]",""))="1","","1")&regexreplace(""&D2:D,"[^0-9]",""),"INVALID")))
```