# Formatting phone number in place in sheet cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image]

I'm working with google sheets and would like to convert US phone numbers to the format:

```
1xxxyyyzzzz
```

eg 402-333-4444 should be turned into 14023334444

I have an apps script validator function which does this:

```
var numbers = 'INVALID' 

if ( parsed_body.hasOwnProperty('PHONE') ) {


  var phone = parsed_body['PHONE'].toString();
  Logger.log(parsed_body);

  numbers = phone.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
  var firstChar = numbers.charAt(0);
  if ( firstChar !== '1'){ numbers = '1'+ numbers}
  Logger.log(numbers);

  if ( numbers.length !== 11){ numbers = 'NOTELEVEN'};
}

parsed_body['PHONE']=numbers;
```

I also asked this question [Validate phonenumbers to specific format using Google Sheet formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60156027/validate-phonenumbers-to-specific-format-using-google-sheet-formula) and obviously it can be done as a formula in an adjacent column. However in my case each row is created by a post request to google sheets from a submitted form and I'd like to format the phone number IN PLACE (ie in the cell) to look like 1aaabbbcccc. Is this possible?

but I'd like to make the sheet do this. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 4):

- For Google Spreadsheet, you want to convert `402-333-4444` to `14023334444` by adding `1`.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In order to achieve your goal, I would like to propose to overwrite the converted values to the cells.

#### Sample script:

In this sample script, it supposes that the values are put to the cells "D2:D". When you run the script, the cells "A2:A" is overwritten by the converted values.

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange(2, 4, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1);  // Column "D"
  const values = range.getValues();
  const converted = values.map(([v]) => {
    if (/\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/.test(v)) {
      let temp = v.replace(/-/g, "");
      console.log(v.charAt(0))
      const tempV = v.charAt(0) != 1 ? 1 + temp : temp;
      return [tempV.length == 11 ? tempV : v];
    }
    return [v];
  });
  range.setValues(converted);
}
```

#### Note:

- When you want to also convert `402 333 4444` to `14023334444`, please modify as follows.

  - From

    ```
    if (/\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/.test(v)) {
      let temp = v.replace(/-/g, "");
    ```
  - To

    ```
    if (/\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}|\d{3} \d{3} \d{4}/.test(v)) {
      let temp = v.replace(/-| /g, "");
    ```

Comment: As usual you came up with a great answer and I upvoted it. I was wondering if it could be sone without apps script using built in functions like https://support.google.com/docs/thread/6013336?hl=en

Comment: @user61629 Thank you for replying.  I apologize for the inconvenience. I had thought that you wanted to do this using Google Apps Script. But your goal is to achieve using the built-in functions of Spreadsheet. Is my understanding correct?