# Format Phone Numbers in Sheets using Google App Script from 1xxxxxxxxxx to xxx-xxx-xxxx

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to modify the following Google App Script to convert phone numbers from

11-digits to 10 digits with hyphens. So the script would need to remove the leading 1 and add the hyphens.

For example: 19734776262 to 973-477-6262

The following script does the opposite. Found on [Formatting phone number in place in sheet cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61279657/formatting-phone-number-in-place-in-sheet-cell)

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange(2, 4, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1);  // Column "D"
  const values = range.getValues();
  const converted = values.map(([v]) => {
    if (/\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/.test(v)) {
      let temp = v.replace(/-/g, "");
      console.log(v.charAt(0))
      const tempV = v.charAt(0) != 1 ? 1 + temp : temp;
      return [tempV.length == 11 ? tempV : v];
    }
    return [v];
  });
  range.setValues(converted);
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to get substrings from a string?

Answer (score 2):

If a formula solution works for you here is my approach, otherwise excuse me for the misunderstanding:

```
=CONCATENATE(left(right(A1,len(A1)-1),3),"-",mid(right(A1,len(A1)-1),4,3),"-",right(A1,4))
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 2):

As [Marios](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11225291/marios) also mentioned, *"If a formula solution works for you here is my approach"*

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(TEXT(I1,"0-000-000-0000"),"-(.*)")
```

To apply the above formula to a range of cells, please use:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(I1:I="",,REGEXEXTRACT(TEXT(I1:I,"0-000-000-0000"),"-(.*)")))
```

*(Please adjust ranges to your needs)*

[image]

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)
- [`TEXT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139)

Comment: perfect solution! this is way better than mine.

Answer (score 2):

Using [regex](/questions/tagged/regex):

```
=RIGHT(REGEXREPLACE(A2,"(?:^1)?(\d{3})","-$1"),12)
```

- `REGEXREPLACE` the following pattern

  - `(?:^1)?` - A leading `1` (optional)- non capturing group
  - `\d{3}` - exactly 3 occurrences of a `d`igit
  - `(...)` - capture group `$1`
- replace with `-$1` - leading hyphen `-` and captured group
- `RIGHT` to get exactly 12 right most characters

Comment: How would I modify your original script to apply this formula? The challenge I have is that the data is coming in via a form submission so I don’t want to add a column to format the data. Does this make sense?

Comment: @DataRobot That does make sense. But If you show your attempts at scripting to achieve the desired result (by editing your question), I may be able to help you. If you have no idea, Consider doing "codelabs" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: Thank you. The code I included in the original post was actually written by you. :)

Comment: @DataRobot It seems it's written by Tanaike here and not me.

Answer (score 2):

If you *really* want a script and not a formula, this script will do it. (I modified the one you provided.)

```
function myFunction() 
{
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.
  
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange('D:D');  // Column "D"
  const values = range.getValues();
  const converted = values.map(([v]) => {
    if (/^\d{11}$/.test(v))
    {
      let sv = v.toString();
      return [[sv.substr(1, 3), sv.substr(4, 3), sv.substr(7)].join('-')];
    }
    return [v];
  });
    
  range.setValues(converted);
}
```

It just takes the substring chunks from the input and joins them together.